# How to plot |z-1| = 2 in a specified domain in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do I plot |z-1| = 2, from -10 to +10 in the real line and from -10i to +10i on the complex line? I've been trying for ages and seems like I can't get it right. Z stands for a complex number!

Also, could I use as well the x+iy notation in mathematica? or a+ib?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a contour plot:

```
ContourPlot[Abs[x + I y] == 2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

To just plot a (real-valued) function:

```
Plot3D[Abs[x + I y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

Choice of variable names is, of course, completely arbitrary.

Just for fun: with some smart choices, you can plot a complex-valued complex function, for example by piecing together Plot3D or ContourPlot3D with Animate.

Comment: Hm, I want it in the complex plane. If you plot what you showed me, you'll see it's completely different from what I asked.

Comment: Oh, I see, you wanted a contour plot. See above.